Are there self-adjoint operators with eigenvalues 1, -1 that are not isometries?
Let $f$ be a self-adjoint operator in an euclidean metric vector space $(V, g)$.
a) Prove that the following are equivalent.
i) The only eigenvalues of $f$ are 0, 1.
ii) $f$ is an orthogonal proyection.
b) Is it possible to replace 0, 1 with other pair of numbers so that (ii) becomes the following?
ii') $f$ is an isometry from $(V,g)$ to itself.
I´ve proved part (a). For (b) I´ve shown that if $f$ is an isometry and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is an eigenvalue whose corresponding eigenvector is $v \in V$, $v\neq 0$, then
$$
g(v, v) = g(f(v), f(v)) = g(\lambda v, \lambda v) = \lambda^{2} g(v, v)
$$
so since $g$ is euclidean $\lambda^{2} = 1$, which shows that its only eigenvalues are $1, -1$. However, for the converse I´ve come up with a counterexample with an operator that is not self-adjoint. Namely $f(x, y) = (x, x+y)$ infor every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ has only 1 as an eigenvalue but it is not an isometry if we take the standard inner product of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ as the metric, but it also not self-adjoint. So my question is, is the converse true when $f$ is self-adjoint? If not, where should I look for a counterexample?

There are isometries that are not self-adjoint; isometries that are self-adjoint are precisely orthogonal reflections in some subspace. If you keep the assumption that $f$ is self-adjoint as a given, then yes, the set of such operators that are isometries does coincide with the operators with eigenvalues $1$ and/or $-1$. But, other isometries (such as most rotations) are not self-adjoint at all. What's more, such isometries won't have all real eigenvalues.

Thank you. I’ll try to come up with the proof. Yes, I was aware that rotations may not even have real eigenvalues

I don't know what a "euclidean metric vector space" is. But if $f$ is linear in $\mathbf{R}^n$ you can just diagonalize $f$.

An inner product space. That’s the way it is referred to in the course I’m taking
